# Custom Objects to CSV PowerShell

Tags: object, powershell, csv

```
  #Function to get the computerlist: Name,OS,IPv4, IPv6,DiskInfo
 function Get-ComputerListnDiskInfo{
 [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)] [string[]]$ComputerName 
  )
  BEGIN {
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory -Cmdlet Get-ADComputer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  }
  PROCESS {

    try{
        $computerinfo = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystem
        #Information about Name,Ipv4,IPv6,Device,VolumeName,Free,Busy,Size,Pfree,Pbusy for ALL COMPUTERS container
        $AllComputerInfo = @()
        foreach ($comp in $computerinfo){
            #Testing if computers is ON LINE
            $TestCon = Tester $comp.name
            $test = $TestCon.BooleanV
            if($test) {
                #write-output "$Test"
                $PhysicalDisks = Get-WMIObject -computername $comp.name -query "SELECT * from win32_logicaldisk where DriveType = 3" | Select Deviceid,VolumeName,FreeSpace,Size
                $Target = @()
                #Create the Object foreach disk and append in the Target Variable
                $GetOPNHealthStatus = Get-PhysicalDisk | select FriendlyName,OperationalStatus,HealthStatus

                Write-Output "$PhysicalDisk.count"

                #write-output $GetOPNHealthStatus.OperationalStatus
                $i=0
                foreach ($disk in $physicalDisks){

                    #Get all Items: size,free,busy,pfree and pbusy disk space info (can add a number at the end to set decimals)
                    $Size=FormatNSetSizeFreeSpace $disk.Size
                    $Free=FormatNSetSizeFreeSpace $disk.FreeSpace
                    $Busy=FormatNSetBusySpace $disk.Size $disk.FreeSpace
                    $Pfree=PercentFreeBusy $Free $size
                    $PBusy=PercentFreeBusy $Busy $size

                    #Create a new Object using all the info
                    $result =New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                        Device=$disk.DeviceID
                        VolumeName=$disk.VolumeName
                        Size=$Size
                        Free=$Free
                        Busy=$Busy
                        Pfree = $PFree
                        PBusy = $PBusy
                        OPStatus = $GetOPNHealthStatus.OperationalStatus[$i]
                        HStatus  = $GetOPNHealthStatus.HealthStatus[$i]
                    }

                    $i++
                    #add this info to the target array
                    $Target+= $result
                }


                    #Add all info into new object
                    $allIComnDiskInfo=New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                        Name = $comp.Name
                        OS = $comp.OperatingSystem
                        IPV4 =  $TestCon.IPv4
                        IPV6 =  $TestCon.IPv6
                        disksInfo = $Target
                    }
                #and Fill any just add this info to the $Allcomputer info (just online computer's)
                $AllComputerInfo+= $allIComnDiskInfo
            }   
        }
        return $AllComputerInfo
    }
    Catch{
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
  }
}

$test = Get-ComputerListnDiskInfo
```

running $test

```
$test = Get-ComputerListnDiskInfo
```

$test

```
disksInfo : {@{PBusy=8,148; VolumeName=; Busy=10,306; Pfree=91,853; Free=116,178; Device=C:; Size=126,483; OPStatus=O; HStatus=H}}
Name      : DC2012
OS        : Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
IPV4      : 192.168.1.251
IPV6      : fe80::cd63:76bf:3d2b:340f%12
```

And running

```
$test | Export-Csv here.csv
```

I got this:

```
#TYPE System.String
"Length"
"6"
```

Why is happening this?

Why I don't get all this info?

And how should I search the info contained in the "diskInfo" variable

I tried to pass this $test variable to another function to format it and It seem not to work:

Thank you in advance for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start out with, you aren't just outputting a custom object, or an array of custom objects. But that's not the first problem I see. The first problem I see is that you have this big function that has a parameter, and then you do this:

```
$test = Get-ComputerListnDiskInfo
```

So you call that function with no arguments, so it has no computer to run it against. Some of the parts of the function will probably default to the local computer, but will they all? I don't know, maybe.

So what does `$test` actually contain? An array. Of what? Well, the first thing that the function outputs is a string:

```
Write-Output "$PhysicalDisk.count"
```

So the first item in your array is a string. Then you build a bunch of custom objects and arrays, and what not, and you `Return` those. Great, the next item in your `$test` array is a custom object. But $test is not an array of custom objects, or a single custom object, it is an array with a variety of things within it.

That is why `Export-CSV` will not work.

Comment: Mmm if what you just said is correct
Then why when I run the $test it has the correct information.
As far as I know when you run it with no arguments they are going to the default. I will correct the $computername to $computerInfo. I run it with no arguments because she will get the info in the process so is not required that argument.

$Test contains this: 
disksInfo : {@{PBusy=8,148; VolumeName=; Busy=10,306; Pfree=91,853; Free=116,178; Device=C:; Size=126,483; OPStatus=O; HStatus=H}}
Name      : DC2012
OS        : Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
IPV4      : 192.168.1.251
IPV6      : ...

Comment: It still has the right information, it's just not stored in a fashion in which you can easily access it like you would like to. I have a feeling that `$test[1]` probably has what you want, and could be piped to export-csv like you want it to.

Comment: You were right @TheMadTechnician, $test[1] | Export-csv here.csv Worked...

Now I have got this:
"disksInfo","Name","OS","IPV4","IPV6"
"System.Object[]","DC2012","Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard","192.168.1.251","fe80::cd63:76bf:3d2b:340f%12"

And I would like to export the Diskinfo information as well...

Comment: That is a problem because of how you are storing your data. You have an array nested within your PSCustomObject, and CSV file format does not support nested arrays. Please edit your question with an example of your desired output and I'll see what I can do to help you out with a bit of a re-write of your code to get you there.

Comment: I have the "name" "OS "IPv4" and "IPV6" members that are being exported as requested: "DC2012","Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard","192.168.1.251","fe80::cd63:76bf:3d2b:340f%12"

Now This server has 2 drives and all this info is stored in the diskinfo Object, I think this object is a custom PSOBject array within the object and associated to the current server "DC2012".

So the output would be something like:
"Name" "IPv4" "IPv6" "DriveInfo"
DC2012 192..   fe80..   C:   Size   Free   Busy PFree Pbusy HStatus OStatus

Comment: Yeah, so your comment is a jumble of text. Please edit your question and format your desired output as something that I can read without going cross-eyed.

Comment: Or if you really don't want to edit your question feel free to mark my answer as accepted (if you feel it appropriate), since I did answer your original question as to why it wouldn't output as a CSV correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the issue is this one:
I have an system.object[] in the output while using CSV.

[object or similar output when using export-csv](http://learn-powershell.net/2014/01/24/avoiding-system-object-or-similar-output-when-using-export-csv/)